# Need help pulling data out of mysql into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am pulling data out of a data base. As I seem to be having trouble with arrays and multidimensional arrays I need some help.

In the database I am pulling the following information:
id, platoon, name, position, status

I need to put all of this into an array.

As there are over 150 names, with many holding the same position.

here is the code I am using:

```
    $sql='SELECT  id, position, platoon, name, status FROM ost_platoon_assignments';
    $users=db_query($sql);
    $num=db_num_rows($users);
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($users)) {
        $info = array(
           $row['position'] => array(
            $row['platoon'] => array("name" =>$row['name'], "status" => $row['status']),
          ),
        );
     }
```

I want to list via a table by those in a particular position:

example:

```
    <table border="1">
    <?
    foreach ($info as $position => $names) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> {$position} </td>";
       foreach ($names as $name) {
        if ($name[name] =="") {$name[name] = "Vacant"; }
        echo "<td class=\"status{$name[status]}\"> {$name[name]} </td>";
       }
        echo "</tr>";
     }
    ?>
    </table>
```

What am I missing?  When I run this it only gives me the last entry.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of $info with each iteration of your while statement.
If you want to store all your data in array structure like this:

```
$info = array(
    'general' => array(
        array( /* general 1 */ ),
        array( /* general 2 */ ),
        array( /* general 3 */ )
    ),
    'colonel' => array(
        array( /* colonel 1 */ ),
        array( /* colonel 2 */ ),
    ),
    // .....
)
```

Then use a process like the following: (Note I'm using PDO, you could also use PHP'S mysqli, but use one of these instead of PHP's mysql library which is deprecated).

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$result = $conn->query('SELECT  id, position, platoon, name, status FROM ost_platoon_assignments');

$info = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $info[$row['position']][] = $row;
}
```

You can then loop through each user by position like this

```
foreach ($info as $position => $users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Antony, thank you for your help. I am trying to display the array and while it prints I need to sort the array.  For instance.  I have members in "A" platoon and others in "B" platoon and etc.  I am trying to list them in a single row by position sorted by platoon.  Can you provide some insight

Comment: Hi Mike. Rather than trying to sort the array. You should try changing the query to give you sorted results.

"SELECT  id, position, platoon, name, status FROM ost_platoon_assignments order by platoon, position"

This will sort alphabetically if that's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 $info[] = array( ..... );
      ^^-----
```

instead. Right now you're continually OVERWRITING `$info` with every result row being retrieved. The `[]` notation will PUSH the new row onto the `$info` array, instead of simply replacing what was there previously.